# How to get a tangent of a point in a golden spiral with HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've got a problem with some html5 canvas stuff...

With a lot of patience I've draw a golden spiral with a X number of dots on it (equally distributed).
This dots must become a little perpendicular lines.
Perpendicular to what?
In my mind, the line must be perpendicular to the tangent line of that point of a spiral.
So, that's the questions:
- How can I get the tangent line of a point in a golden spiral?
- Once I find the tangent, how can I draw a line perpendicular to it starting from my point xy?

The main problem is that, in canvas (as far I know), a line must have a start and end already known, while I have only the xystart

This is the jfiddle with the spiral code.
https://jsfiddle.net/MasterFO/bho3v6hs/2/

```
function spiral_render(){
    var c = document.getElementById('c');
    var context = c.getContext("2d");
    var centerx = (context.canvas.width / 2)+5;
    var centery = (context.canvas.height / 2)+100;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 582, 620);
    context.moveTo(centerx, centery);
    context.beginPath();

    var dots_coordinates = [];

    a = parseFloat(0.41);
    b = parseFloat(0.23);
    var dots = 20;  //How many dots
    rounds = parseFloat(180);
    strength = parseFloat(30);

    sample = strength * 360;
    start = -rounds*(3.14);
    end = rounds*(3.14);
    step = (end - start) / sample;

    var distance = parseInt((sample/dots)/2.6);    //Distance between dots

    k = 0;
    //Draw the golden spiral
    for (var i = 1; i <= sample; i++) {
        r = start+i*step;
        t = (1/b)*Math.log(r/a);    //Phi angle of spiral

        x = centerx + r* Math.cos(t);
        y = centery + r* Math.sin(t);

        if (i % distance == 0 && k <=dots && i > 5600) {
            if(x && y){
                dots_coordinates.push([x,y]);
                k++;
            }
        }
        context.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    context.lineWidth = 0.5;
    context.strokeStyle = "#000";
    context.stroke();

    //Draw the dots in sequential mode
    context.moveTo(centerx, centery);
    var i = 0;
    inter = setInterval(function() {

        xp = Math.floor( dots_coordinates[i][0] );
        yp = Math.floor( dots_coordinates[i][1] );

        context.beginPath();
        context.lineTo(xp, yp);
        context.arc(xp, yp, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI , false);
        context.fillStyle = '#C4071A';
        context.fill();

        i++;

        if (i == (dots_coordinates.length)) {
            clearInterval(inter);
        }

    }, 50);
}
```

Someone have any idea?

Comment: Find the slope using the two neighboring points, make a line based on that slope and draw it on your point.

Comment: something like this : https://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/bho3v6hs/5/ ?

Comment: You're welcome ! You want it explained ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code to draw a perpendicular line at a dot of your choise. This code will not work on the first and last dot unfortunately. Credits to [Spencer Wieczorek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3149020/spencer-wieczorek) who suggested this method in his comment above.

In order to overcome only having a starting point is to use Math.sin() and Math.cos() multiplied with the length that you want your line to have.

```
var dotIndex = 11;
var lineLength = 50;
var myX = dots_coordinates[dotIndex-1][0]-dots_coordinates[dotIndex+1][0];
var myY = dots_coordinates[dotIndex-1][1]-dots_coordinates[dotIndex+1][1];
var theta = Math.atan2(-myY, myX);
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(dots_coordinates[dotIndex][0],dots_coordinates[dotIndex][1]);
context.lineTo(dots_coordinates[dotIndex][0]+Math.sin(theta)*lineLength,dots_coordinates[dotIndex][1]+Math.cos(theta)*lineLength);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
```